# Domain Expired, Renewed it but not refreshing on computers, only Cell phones

Tags: networking, domain

Our domain had expired. We renewed it but now we are having a problem viewing our website from our work computers. We have both Mac and Windows machines and both give us an error viewing our website, however we are able to access it via our cell phones and iPads as long as we have the wifi turned OFF.

I believe this is a network error and have restarted both our modem and router to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

It's a DNS cache issue, as is evidenced by the different behavior between LAN devices and Cellular devices (which use different DNS servers).

Give it a few hours and the problem will likely resolve itself.

Answer (score 3):

What is the error you are getting?

This would most likely be an issue with your onsite DNS server caching the old values. Try resetting your DNS cache on your DNS server. How to do this depends on the DNS server you are using. You would also have to flush the DNS cache on your devices.

For Windows, open a command prompt, and enter the following:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

For Mac, open terminal and enter the following:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```